# Is there something like an Iterator, but with functions like Streams?

Tags: java, stream, iterator, memory-optimization

So basically what I am trying to do is the following:

1. Load Batch of Data from the Database
2. Map that data (`Object[]` query result) to a class representing the data in a readable format
3. Write to File
4. Repeat until query gets no more results

I listed the structures that I am familiar with that seem to fit the need and why they don't fit my needs.

- Iterator → Has no option to map and filter without calling `next()`

  - I need to define the map function in a subclass though without actually having the data (similar to a stream), so that I can pass the "Stream" way up to a calling class and only there call `next`, which then calls all the map functions as a result
- Stream → All data needs to be available before mapping and filtering is possible
- Observable → Sends data as soon as it comes available. I need to process it in sync though

To get more of a feeling what I am trying to do, I made a small example:

```java
// Disclaimer: "Something" is the structure I am not sure of now. 
// Could be an Iterator or something else that fits (Thats the question)
public class Orchestrator {
    @Inject
    private DataGetter dataGetter;

    public void doWork() {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("filename");

        // Write the formatted data to the file
        dataGetter.getData()
            .forEach(data -> writer.writeToFile(data));
    }
}

public class FileWriter {
    public void writeToFile(List<Thing> data) {
        // Write to file
    }
}

public class DataGetter {
    @Inject
    private ThingDao thingDao;

    public Something<List<Thing>> getData() {

        // Map data to the correct format and return that
        return thingDao.getThings()
            .map(partialResult -> /* map to object */);
    }
}

public class ThingDao {

    public Something<List<Object[]>> getThings() {
        Query q = ...;
        // Dont know what to return
    }
}
```

What I have got so far:

I tried to go from the base of an Iterator, because it's the only one that really fulfills my memory requirements. Then I have added some methods to map and loop over the data. It's not really a robust design though and it's going to be harder than I thought, so I wanted to know if there is anything out there already that does what I need.

```java
public class QIterator<E> implements Iterator<List<E>> {
    public static String QUERY_OFFSET = "queryOffset";
    public static String QUERY_LIMIT = "queryLimit";

    private Query query;

    private long lastResultIndex = 0;
    private long batchSize;

    private Function<List<Object>, List<E>> mapper;

    public QIterator(Query query, long batchSize) {
        this.query = query;
        this.batchSize = batchSize;
    }

    public QIterator(Query query, long batchSize, Function<List<Object>, List<E>> mapper) {
        this(query, batchSize);
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return lastResultIndex % batchSize == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public List<E> next() {
        query.setParameter(QueryIterator.QUERY_OFFSET, lastResultIndex);
        query.setParameter(QueryIterator.QUERY_LIMIT, batchSize);

        List<Object> result = (List<Object>) query.getResultList(); // unchecked
        lastResultIndex += result.size();

        List<E> mappedResult;
        if (mapper != null) {
            mappedResult = mapper.apply(result);
        } else {
            mappedResult = (List<E>) result; // unchecked
        }

        return mappedResult;
    }

    public <R> QIterator<R> map(Function<List<E>, List<R>> appendingMapper) {
        return new QIterator<>(query, batchSize, (data) -> {
            if (this.mapper != null) {
                return appendingMapper.apply(this.mapper.apply(data));
            } else {
                return appendingMapper.apply((List<E>) data);
            }
        });
    }

    public void forEach(BiConsumer<List<E>, Integer> consumer) {
        for (int i = 0; this.hasNext(); i++) {
            consumer.accept(this.next(), i);
        }
    }
}
```

This works so far, but has some `unchecked` assignments which I do not really like and also I would like to have the ability to "append" one QIterator to another which is not hard by itself, but it should also take the maps that follow after the append.

Comment: What do you mean by *Stream → All data needs to be available before mapping and filtering is possible*? Filtering happens element by element, either before or after mapping.

Comment: Yes but you need to have a stream of all your data before mapping or filtering it. I can't load all my data because it's too big, so I need to work it in an unknown amount of small batches. But maybe I am misthinking something here, so if you have an idea on how to solve this problem with Streams, I would be more than glad to hear it! @Bohemian

Comment: Like streams are just objects that store information (mapping and filtering functions and so on) until one specific function is called that executes the stream (like forEach or collect). Once the stream is executed, I can't add more data and execute the next batch. Do you get what I mean? @Bohemian

Comment: `Stream.of("a", "b").map(yourMapper).filter(yourFilter).iterator()`?

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to tell me? I don't know anything of `a` and `b` before executing. I don't even know if it's just a and b...could be a c and d there too if you know what I mean? I would need a stream that does run through the whole chain and just then execute the next item. And the next item is not allowed to be in memory before the first item is processed and thrown out of it. @Lino

Comment: `Stream` doesn't require all data to be available up front. You can have infinite streams too, e.g. `IntStream infinite = new java.util.Random().ints();`.

Comment: *"streams are just objects that store information"* --- Wrong, streams don't store information at all. Streams are the *processing instructions* (the pipeline) for handling data. The data itself is obtained from a `Spliterator`, which is kind of like the next generation of an `Iterator`.

Comment: I meant information on how to transform/filter/... the incoming data, but yeah I get what you mean. @Andreas

Comment: How would I apply this to my example? Or is there any site I could check to get similar examples? I only used Streams to transform Collections up until now @Kayaman

Comment: So what you are saying is that the DAO doesn't give you all the information, but only gives you the information in blocks, and you have to call the DAO to get the next block of data? Like pagination, where is will give you one page of data, then you have to make another call to get another page of data, but you want to process all the data in a single stream, even though it is only available one page at a time?

Comment: Or is that `Something<List<Thing>>` really a `Stream<List<Thing>>`? If so, why not just call `flatMap()` on it to get a `Stream<Thing>`?

Comment: Yeah sounds about right @Andreas The reasoning is, that if I would just get the data one after another, I would have to do a lot of manual work (passing limits and stuff in every function) to keep track of where I am and cant extract that into a more general function.

Comment: No Something is the thing in question. I am not sure what to use yet. Currently I tried implementing it with an Iterator as you can see in the example below. So it would be a `QIterator<Thing>` @Andreas

Comment: You have a classic problem of batching data from DB to file. Performance and memory are usually the tripping blocks. There are efficient ways to do those especially with low level mechanisms. A naive solution that you're building here would not perform very well with large amounts of data. However if you'll be working with relatively small amounts of data, and need a lot of logic code, it might be doable. Depending on your database, you could look for a driver that can stream the data directly, alleviating memory issues.

Comment: "There are efficient ways to do those especially with low level mechanisms". Care to share? If you want to tell me that I just should do it manually, I know how to do that. I don't know why my solution should not perform very good at large. I don't see a single point where this would take immensely more computing power or memory than just writing everything in a single function. @Kayaman

Comment: Depends on the database, but they have fast inbuilt mechanisms for importing/exporting data which you can hook up to, and you can easily get 100 times the performance you get with even decently written regular code. Of course the data is usually handled in some generic data format like CSV, so if you intend to do any data transformation, it requires some trickery. As for the performance of your code, you may not see it (do you often  **see** performance from code?), but if you don't trust my experience, you can test it yourself.

Comment: Oracle is the database. I know that I can get better results with Transformation/Filtering directly on the DB, but sadly this is one of the cases where this is not possible. I do performance tests before and after, so yes I do see it (It's a refactoring because of a OutOfMem crash in prod) @Kayaman btw it's obviously going to be slower, as its multiple select statements, but that's to expect anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a DAO that provides data in a paginated manner, e.g. by applying the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses to the underlying SQL. Such a DAO class would have a method that takes those values as argument, i.e. the method would conform to the following functional method:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface PagedDao<T> {
    List<T> getData(int offset, int limit);
}
```

E.g. calling `getData(0, 20)` would return the first 20 rows (page 1), calling `getData(60, 20)` would return the 20 rows on page 4. If the method returns less than 20 rows, it means we got the last page. Asking for data after the last row will return an empty list.

For the demo below, we can mock such a DAO class:

```java
public class MockDao {
    private final int rowCount;
    public MockDao(int rowCount) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
    }
    public List<SimpleRow> getSimpleRows(int offset, int limit) {
        System.out.println("DEBUG: getData(" + offset + ", " + limit + ")");
        if (offset < 0 || limit <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        List<SimpleRow> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0, rowNo = offset + 1; i < limit && rowNo <= this.rowCount; i++, rowNo++)
            data.add(new SimpleRow("Row #" + rowNo));
        System.out.println("DEBUG:   data = " + data);
        return data;
    }
}

public class SimpleRow {
    private final String data;
    public SimpleRow(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Row[data=" + this.data + "]";
    }
}
```

If you then want to generate a [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of rows from that method, streaming all rows in blocks of a certain size, we need a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html) for that, so we can use [**`StreamSupport.stream(Spliterator<T> spliterator, boolean parallel)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#stream-java.util.Spliterator-boolean-) to create a stream.

Here is an implementation of such a `Spliterator`:

```java
public class PagedDaoSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    private final PagedDao<T> dao;
    private final int blockSize;
    private int nextOffset;
    private List<T> data;
    private int dataIdx;
    public PagedDaoSpliterator(PagedDao<T> dao, int blockSize) {
        if (blockSize <= 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.dao = Objects.requireNonNull(dao);
        this.blockSize = blockSize;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (this.data == null) {
            if (this.nextOffset == -1/*At end*/)
                return false; // Already at end
            this.data = this.dao.getData(this.nextOffset, this.blockSize);
            this.dataIdx = 0;
            if (this.data.size() < this.blockSize)
                this.nextOffset = -1/*At end, after this data*/;
            else
                this.nextOffset += data.size();
            if (this.data.isEmpty()) {
                this.data = null;
                return false; // At end
            }
        }
        action.accept(this.data.get(this.dataIdx++));
        if (this.dataIdx == this.data.size())
            this.data = null;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return null; // Parallel processing not supported
    }
    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE; // Unknown
    }
    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return ORDERED | NONNULL;
    }
}
```

We can now test that using the mock DAO above:

```java
MockDao dao = new MockDao(13);
Stream<SimpleRow> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
        new PagedDaoSpliterator<>(dao::getSimpleRows, 5), /*parallel*/false);
stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
DEBUG: getData(0, 5)
DEBUG:   data = [Row[data=Row #1], Row[data=Row #2], Row[data=Row #3], Row[data=Row #4], Row[data=Row #5]]
Row[data=Row #1]
Row[data=Row #2]
Row[data=Row #3]
Row[data=Row #4]
Row[data=Row #5]
DEBUG: getData(5, 5)
DEBUG:   data = [Row[data=Row #6], Row[data=Row #7], Row[data=Row #8], Row[data=Row #9], Row[data=Row #10]]
Row[data=Row #6]
Row[data=Row #7]
Row[data=Row #8]
Row[data=Row #9]
Row[data=Row #10]
DEBUG: getData(10, 5)
DEBUG:   data = [Row[data=Row #11], Row[data=Row #12], Row[data=Row #13]]
Row[data=Row #11]
Row[data=Row #12]
Row[data=Row #13]
```

As can be seen, we get 13 rows of data, retrieved from the database in blocks of 5 rows.

The data is not retrieved from the database until it is needed, causing low memory footprint, depending on block size and the stream operation not caching the data.

Comment: Or there’s the [easy way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63584514/256196) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line as follows:

```
stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryThatReturnsAllRowsOrdered);
Stream.generate(rs.next() ? map(rs) : null)
  .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull)
  .filter(<some predicate>)
  .forEach(<some operation);
```

This starts processing when the first row is returned from the query and continues in parallel with the database until all rows have been read.

This approach only has one row in memory at a time, and minimises the load on the database by only running 1 query.

Mapping from a `ResultSet` is far more easy and natural than mapping from `Object[]` because you can access columns by *name* and with properly typed values, eg:

```
MyDao map(ResultSet rs) {
    try {
        String someStr = rs.getString("COLUMN_X");
        int someInt = rs.getInt("COLUMN_Y"):
        return new MyDao(someStr, someInt);
    } catch (SQLException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This of source entirely ignores the fact that OP explicitly stated that the code "Loads Batch of Data from the Database", i.e. the data is retrieved in chunks, each chunk/batch being a `List<?>`. Otherwise, yeah, a single query is better for overall performance.

Comment: @Andreas I think OP *assumed* batch was needed becasue the result set is too big to handle as one giant result, but didn't realise that that situation is avoidable by using a cursor. M aproach uses constant memory and puts a single constant amount of load on the database, whereas chunking would put roughly the number of chunks times as much load.

Comment: Assuming the JDBC driver supports cursor mode, and is configured to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I did not assume batch was needed. It is more performant with batches in the following operations. With this, I would have to create batches again by hand. Also, I am not really sure if I understand the "parallel" part correctly, but if I do it's another point, why I shouldn't use this → The results HAVE to stay in order and need to be processed in sequence. But this is definitely a clean solution, if that would not be the case.

Comment: @MauriceNino what do you mean "batches are more efficient"? I seriously doubt it - batches require multiple  queries - this  requires only one. This solution is lighter on both database and application. "parallel" means "the database is delivering rows *and* the application is processing rows *at the same time*".

Comment: The rows are compared to each other in the code and in the end written to a file. Both operations are more efficient, when done in batches or "at best" only once...which is not possible in this situation. Ok then that is the kind of "parallel" that I thought - it does not work because it needs to be in order. PS: The comparison is not doable in the Query itself

Comment: @MauriceNino with this solution processing is *not* in parallel! It is sequential. As I  said before, the "parallel" part is the application and the database executing in parallel with each other. With the other answer and your solution, the database and application execute *sequentially*, ie the database query returns all rows (of a batch) *then* the application processes all rows (of the batch). This answer processes each row as it is returned, ie *before* the entire result set has been returned. Please elaborate on exactly what you mean by "rows are compared to each other".

Comment: Oh ok misunderstood, thought you meant "application is processing rows at the same time", like multiple rows in parallel. Whatever. It will be compared to data acquired from a web service.